# How to load different HTML Content based on different Screen Size whith JS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I intend for screen sizes greater then 600px to display a slider and for less than 600px to display the same content without the slider. I'm using Bootstrap 4 and Wordpress. For some reason my code isn't returning anything at all. Here is the code of the wordpress template:

```
<div class="container-fluid custom-bg-color" id="seccion-portafolio">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="portafolio-variable-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
<script>

(function () {

var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
if (viewportWidth > 600) {    
$('#portafolio-variable-content').load('slider.php');
$('#portafolio-variable-content').html("<p>Another test</p>")

} else {    
$('#portafolio-variable-content').load('no-slider-content.php');
}    
}());
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS media rules?

Comment: Those php paths don't look like wordpress ajax endpoints. Also is the js code at end of the html or in the `<head>`?

Comment: I dont want to use css because I prefer to don't load a content instead of just hiding it. It is in the end of the template. Can't i just call /load a template inside my custom theme?

Comment: I have tested your code in jsfiddle.net, it works. Problem may be in the URLs of "slider.php" and "no-slider-content.php". May you try to put there full url.. something like "https://.../slider.php"? Maybe it will help. I hope the php files are located on the same server and you will not get cross origin request error there.

Comment: Currently I'm working on local installation/localhost weird thing is even if I try to output a console message nothing happens.. double checked the path..but if can't even get the console to work... nothings is being populated inside #portafolio-variable-content div..